# how can i add the viewer node to the shader editor?

Tags: shader-nodes

I know "normally" shift-ctrl left mouse click -> viewer node will be added.

I am using 3.3. alpha version and a mac and it doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestions?

Node wrangler is enabled.

[image]

i am a bit concerned that it might be because shift control left mouse is double used: select toggle and preview node...

i deleted all double for shift control -> didn't work either :(

it's not a hardware problem -> 2.93 is working that way

Comment: Do you have the node Wrangler addon enabled?

Comment: yes of course ;)

Comment: Just checking! :^)

Comment: i know...i wanted to just answer yes...but i wasn't allowed... ;)

Comment: I assume you've checked node wrangler's settings in Preferences -> Add-Ons -> Node: Node Wrangler -> Show Hotkey List to see if the setting changed?

Comment: :^) Sounds as if it may be a bug in that case, but since I a) don't have a Mac and b) don't have 3.3 Alpha installed....

Comment: it says: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyCzo.png ...and that worked always... :(

Comment: shouldn't be a bug...because that worked :( so maybe i have accidentally killed it somehow

Comment: i opened a bug report...i have no idea... :(